# MPI program for the Poisson equation stuck after one iteration

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90, poisson

I am trying to solve the Poisson Equation in a Square domain [(0,1)--(0,1)] using MPI and overlapping domains. Currently, my code takes an input of the number of domain divisions on X and Y directions, the length of the overlap between two domains as a function of domain length and the number of elemntal divisions in the overlap.

Input file looks like

2,2

10,10

10,10

```
   program main
  !implicit none 
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer  cols, divfx, divfy, iter
  integer  xdiv, ydiv,  info, max_iter, x_shift, y_shift
  integer, allocatable:: ipiv(:) 
  double precision, allocatable :: A(:,:), Ainv(:,:)
  real, allocatable:: edge(:,:)
  double precision, allocatable :: u(:,:), f(:,:)
  double precision, allocatable :: u_exact(:,:)
  allocatable :: Left(:,:), Right(:,:)
  allocatable :: Top(:,:), Bottom(:,:)
  allocatable :: TempLeft(:,:), TempRight(:,:)
  allocatable :: TempTop(:,:), TempBottom(:,:)
  integer myid, master, numprocs, ierr, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  integer i, j, numsent, sender, L, T, R, B
  integer anstype, row, dovfx, dovfy, domx, domy, idx
  real dom1,dom2,buff
  double precision mesh(2), buffer(4), divx, divy, dx, dy, xd, yd
  double precision error, derror, error_norm
  character(len=100) :: domaindata

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)

  master = 0
  divx=0.d0
  divy=0.d0
   ! Input the number of divisions for domain decomposition and calculate sub-domain dimensions.          
  open(1, file='Inputdata.dat', status='old')

!      read(1,*) domx,domy 
!      read(1,*) dovfx,dovfy
!      read(1,*) divfx,divfy
  write(*,*)'Starting the Program'


  write(*,*) "Enter the number of domain divisions in x-direction &
           and y-direction ( Enter 4 if you want three sub-domains)"
  read(1,*) domx,domy 
  write(*,*) domx,domy
  write(*,*) "Total number of sub-domains for the problem" 
  write(*,*) domx*domy
  write(*,*) "Enter the sub-domain overlap in x & y -direction as & 
              a fraction of sub-domain length (multiple of 10)"
  read(1,*)  dovfx,dovfy
  write(*,*) dovfx,dovfy
  write(*,*) "Enter the number of divisions in the overlap in & 
             x & yas a fraction of sub-domain(multiple of 5)"
  read(1,*) divfx,divfy
  write(*,*) divfx,divfy
  divx=1.d0/(((1.d0/domx)/dovfx)/divfx)
  divy=1.d0/(((1.d0/domy)/dovfy)/divfy)
  write(*,*)"Total number of elemental divisions for the &  
            problem domain (0,1) in both dimensions" 
  write(*,*) divx, divy, divx*divy
  write(*,*)"Total number of nodal divisions for the problem domain"
  write(*,*) (divx+1)*(divy+1)

!     time
!   **************************   
  tic = MPI_Wtime(); 


! Maximum number of iterations.   
  max_iter=100 


! Mesh Size

   mesh(1)=1/divx
   mesh(2)=1/divy
   write(*,*)  'Element Size'
   write(*,*) mesh(1), mesh(2)        

  if ( myid .eq. master ) then

!     Send iteration number to subdomain and receive the error from each to 
!       calculate total error.



       write(*,*) 'still1' 
  do 10 iter = 1,max_iter  

  do 20 i = 1,domx*domy
    call MPI_SEND(iter, 1, MPI_INTEGER, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
 20    continue     



 !     Receive results obtained from sub-processor/sub-domain
 !    
  error = 0.d0      
  do 30 i = 1,domx*domy
    call MPI_RECV(d_error  , 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, i, iter, &
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
    error = error + d_error
30   continue
  write(*,*) 'In iteration ', iter, 'cumulative error is', error*1.d0/domx/domy
10   continue      

!     time:
!     *************      
  toc = MPI_Wtime(); 

!     Write results to output 
!     **************************

  write(*,*)
  write(*,*) 'Time taken for parallel computation is: ',(toc-tic)*1000, 'miliseconds'
  else
 !************************************        Slaves receive mesh size for discretization   ******************************************************  

       write(*,*) 'iter', iter

       write(*,*) 'myid', myid
!        Slaves receive corners, then creates a Cartesian grid for finite 
!        difference until done message received, for one iteration.
!        This is done for the first iteration

!        Get Domain ID :


     if (myid.gt.(domx*domy)) goto 200


     write(*,*) 'still31'


  1000     call MPI_RECV(iter, 1, MPI_INTEGER, master, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)   
     if (status(MPI_TAG) .eq. 0) goto 200

     write(*,*) 'still4' 

     if (iter.eq.1) then

     write(*,*) 'still5' 
     dom1=domx
     dom2=domy
     allocate (edge(domx*domy,4)) 


!      Determining the edge matrices for each subdomain - the bounding box
     do  j =1,domx
      do  k=1,domy

                  idx=(j-1)*(domx-1)+k+(j-1)

                  buff=REAL((mod(idx-1,domx)))/domx

                  IF (buff-((1.d0/domx)/dovfx) .gt. 0) THEN
                  buff=buff-((1.d0/domx)/dovfx)
                  ENDIF

                  edge(idx,1) = buff

                    IF ((mod(idx ,domx)) .eq. 0) THEN
                    buff=1
                    ELSE
                    buff=REAL(mod(idx ,domx))/domx
                    ENDIF
                    !write(*,*) buff
                    IF (buff + ((1.d0/domx)/dovfx) .lt. 1) THEN
                    buff=buff+((1.d0/domx)/dovfx)
                    ENDIF                   

                    edge(idx,2) = buff

  !                
                      buff=REAL(floor((idx-1)/dom1))/dom1

                 IF (buff -((1.d0/domy)/dovfy) .gt. 0) THEN
                 buff=buff-((1.d0/domy)/dovfy)       
                 ENDIF

                 edge(idx,3) = buff


                 buff=REAL(ceiling(idx/dom1))/dom1

                 IF (buff+((1.d0/domy)/dovfy) .lt. 1) THEN
                 buff= buff+((1.d0/domy)/dovfy)
                 ENDIF

                 edge(idx,4) = buff
      end do 
     end do 


     write(*,*) myid, edge(myid,:) 


     write(*,*) 'iter', iter

    call Surround_dom(myid,domx,domy,LeftC, RightC, BottomC, TopC)





! Calculate data for the matrices: Divisions in each subdomain. : 
      xdiv=(edge(myid,2)-edge(myid,1))/mesh(1)
      ydiv=(edge(myid,4)-edge(myid,3))/mesh(2)
      dx=mesh(1)
      dy=mesh(2)

         allocate (A((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1))) 
         allocate (Ainv((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)))
         allocate (u((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),1),f((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),1))
         allocate (u_exact((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),1))
         allocate (ipiv((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)))
         allocate (Left((ydiv-1),1),Right((ydiv-1),1))
         allocate (Top((xdiv-1),1), Bottom(((xdiv-1)),1))
         allocate (TempLeft((ydiv-1),1),TempRight((ydiv-1),1))
         allocate (TempTop((xdiv-1),1), TempBottom(((xdiv-1)),1))
         Left    = 0.d0; Right   = 0.d0; Bottom  = 0.d0; Top     = 0.d0;    
         TempLeft    = 0.d0; TempRight   = 0.d0; TempBottom  = 0.d0; TempTop     = 0.d0;
         A=0;

     endif 

        write(*,*) 'still6' 
!        ******************************************************************
!             SendReceive data based on location 
!       ******************************************************************

     if (LeftC.ne.0)  then   
         call MPI_SENDRECV(Left, ydiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, LeftC, iter, &
                           TempLeft, ydiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, LeftC, iter, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr) 
     end if      

     if (RightC.ne.0) then               
         call MPI_SENDRECV(Right, ydiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, RightC, iter, &
                           TempRight, ydiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, RightC, iter, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
     end if 

     if (BottomC.ne.0) then      
         call MPI_SENDRECV(Bottom, xdiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, BottomC, iter, &
                           TempBottom, xdiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, BottomC, iter, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
     end if 

     if (TopC.ne.0) then
         call MPI_SENDRECV(Top, xdiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, TopC, iter, &
                           TempTop, xdiv - 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, TopC, iter, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)   
     end if

     Left = TempLeft  ; 
     Right  = TempRight; 
     Top  = TempTop   ; 
     Bottom = TempBottom;

        write(*,*) 'still7'


!            Form the coefficient matrices          
         do i =1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)
         A(i,i)=-2.d0*(1.d0/(dx**2)+1.d0/(dy**2))
         enddo
         do i=1,(xdiv-2)
         do j=1,(ydiv-1)
         A(i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1),i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1)+1)=1.d0/(dx**2)
         A(i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1)+1,i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1))=1.d0/(dx**2)
         enddo
         enddo
         do i=1,(xdiv-1)
         do j=1,(ydiv-2)
         A(i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1),i+(j)*(xdiv-1))=1.d0/(dy**2)
         A(i+(j)*(xdiv-1),i+(j-1)*(xdiv-1))=1.d0/(dy**2)
         enddo
         enddo


         write(*,*) 'still9' 

         L=1
         T=1
         R=1
         B=1

        write(*,*) 'still10' 

! Impose Boundary Conditions in F matrix 
         do i=1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)

            xd = edge(myid,1) + (dx)*mod(i,(xdiv-1))         
            if (mod(i,xdiv-1).eq.0) xd = edge(myid,1) + (dx)*(xdiv-1)
            yd = edge(myid,3) + (dy)*ceiling(i*1.d0/(xdiv-1))          
     !if (iter.eq.1 .and. myid.eq.2) write(*,*) xd,yd
            u_exact(i,1) = sin(2.d0*3.1415*xd)*sin(2.d0*3.1415*yd)
            f(i,1)       = 8.d0*3.1415*3.1415*u_exact(i,1)


         IF (mod(i,(xdiv-1)) .eq. 1) THEN
          f(i,1)= f(i,1)+Left(L,1)/dx/dx
           L=L+1
          ENDIF 
         IF (mod(i,(xdiv-1)) .eq. 0) THEN
          f(i,1)=f(i,1)+Right(R,1)/dx/dx
           R=R+1
         ENDIF
         IF (i .le. (xdiv-1))  THEN
          f(i,1)=f(i,1)+Bottom(B,1)/dy/dy
           B=B+1
         ENDIF
         IF (i .gt. (xdiv-1)*(ydiv-2)) THEN
          f(i,1)=f(i,1)+Top(T,1)/dy/dy
          T=T+1
          END IF     
 !            enddo 
             enddo  

!Solve AU=F by LU factorization!

        write(*,*) 'still11' 
    do i=1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)
     do j=1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)
      Ainv(i,j)=A(i,j)
    end do
    end do

  ! do i=1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)
   ! write(*,*) myid,Ainv(i,i)
   !end do  


  call DGESV((xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1), 1, A, &
  (xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1), ipiv, f, (xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1), info)

  write(*,*) 'still12' 

  call ErrorNorm(f,u_exact,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1),error_norm)  

 write(*,*) 'still13' 
!       ****************************************************
!       Update boundary conditions based on new solution:   
!       ****************************************************    

 x_shift = divfx-1  ;
 y_shift = divfy-1  ;

!    write(*,*) 'LeftC', myid,LeftC,RightC,TopC,BottomC


 if (LeftC.ne.0) then
        do 50 i = 1,ydiv - 1           
    Left(i,1)   = f((xdiv - 1)*(i - 1) + 1 + x_shift,1)
    !if ((myid.eq.2).and.(iter.eq.1)) write(*,*) 'for left',i, &
                                     !(xdiv - 1)*(i - 1) + 1 + x_shift
50      continue
 end if

 if (RightC.ne.0) then
        do 60 i = 1,ydiv - 1           
    Right(i,1)  = f((xdiv - 1)*i - x_shift,1)
    !if ((myid.eq.1).and.(iter.eq.1)) write(*,*) 'for right',i, &
                                     !(xdiv - 1)*i - x_shift
60      continue
 end if

 if (TopC.ne.0) then
        do 70 i = 1,xdiv - 1           
    Top(i,1)    = f((xdiv - 1)*((ydiv - 2) - y_shift) + i,1)
    !if ((myid.eq.1).and.(iter.eq.1)) write(*,*) 'for top',i, &
                                   !((xdiv - 1)*((ydiv - 2) - y_shift) + i)
70      continue
 end if

 if ( BottomC.ne.0) then
        do 80 i = 1,xdiv - 1           
    Bottom(i,1) = f((xdiv - 1)*y_shift + i,1)
    !if ((myid.eq.3).and.(iter.eq.1)) write(*,*) 'for bottom',i, &
                                   !((xdiv - 1)*y_shift + i)
80      continue
 end if  

     write(*,*) 'still14' 
     TempLeft =Left; 
     TempRight = Right; 
     TempTop = Top;
     TempBottom = Bottom;


 call MPI_SEND(error_norm,  1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, master, iter, & 
                             MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)  

      write(*,*) 'still15'                               

     if (iter.lt.iter_max) go to 1000

!        *********************************************************************************  
!        Write solution to data file to view the results. 
!        *********************************************************************************

   write (domaindata, "(A7,I2,A4)") "domain_",myid,".dat"
   open (unit=myid*10, file = domaindata)
   write (myid*10,*) ' VARIABLE= "X","Y","U_EXACT","U_CALC" '

    do i=1,(xdiv-1)*(ydiv-1)
     xd = edge(myid,1) + (dx)*mod(i,(xdiv-1))        
     if (mod(i,xdiv-1).eq.0) xd = edge(myid,1) + (dx)*(xdiv-1)
     yd = edge(myid,3) + (dy)*ceiling(i*1.d0/(xdiv-1))  
     write (myid*10,*) xd, yd, u_exact(i,1), f(i,1)
     enddo       

        write(*,*) 'still16'     

   if (iter.eq.max_iter) go to 200   
200    continue
    write(*,*) 'still45'
   endif

   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
   stop
   end program main

 subroutine Surround_dom(myid,domx,domy,LeftID, RightID, BottomID, TopID)

implicit none  
integer myid, j, k, domy, domx, BottomID, TopID, LeftID, RightID


 j = ceiling(1.d0*myid/domx)
 k = mod(myid,domx)          
 if (k.eq.0) k = domx

! Domain on the left
if(k.eq.1) then
    LeftID   = 0
else 
    LeftID   = ((j-1)*domx + k) - 1
end if 


! Domain on the Right
if(k.eq.domx) then
    RightID  = 0
else 
    RightID  = ((j-1)*domx + k) + 1 
end if  



! Domain on the Bottom
if(j.eq.1) then
    BottomID = 0
else 
    BottomID = ((j-1)*domx + k) - domx
end if


! Domain on the Top  
if(j.eq.domy) then
   TopID = 0
else 
   TopID    = ((j-1)*domx + k) + domx
end if

return
end

     subroutine ErrorNorm(u,u_exact,N,error_norm)

 implicit none

 double precision u(N), u_exact(N), err, error_norm
 integer i, N

 error_norm = 0.d0


 do 10 i = 1,N   

 err = (u(i) - u_exact(i))
 error_norm = error_norm + err*err

10   continue

 error_norm = sqrt(error_norm)/(N*1.d0)

 return
 end
```

I expect the code to run through all the iterations giving me an respectable error about multiples of 1e-3/1e-4.?

Currently, no error shows up, the code successfully runs for 1 iteration and then doesn't produce any output at all, even after days. It would be really helpful if I could get some guidance. I am sorry since the structure of my code is a awkward, I am just a beginner. It won't run if number of domains is odd or if the number of domains is not equal to number of processors. Any suggestions on how to remove these limitations is also welcome.

Comment: This is a LONG code. Please see [mcve]. It is really necessary that you learn some debugging skills yourself. Try to run the code. Use `gdb -pid` to find out where the code is stuck and tell us some details.

Comment: You should be looking for a deadlock. Always try to run your program with just one process first. Also using file units in the OPEN statement below 10 is not recommended.

Comment: Why are you commenting out `implicit none`? It's provided to help you avoid simple errors like undefined variables. If the code doesn't compile with it in then address those issues first. Also `use mpi` is preferable to `include 'mpif.h`.